# android studio stop runnable handler on user inactivity

Tags: android, android-studio, handler, runnable

I have the following code segment which runs in the on create method of an Activity.
It is set up to run every few seconds (20 at the moment). 
It basically looks for new location every 20 seconds and updates some edit texts.
However when I close the app or I am inactive on the app - it carries on running (I see the Toast on my screen while doing other things on my phone). Is there a way to stop this code from running when the user exits the activity (or even better when the user is inactive - say after 60 seconds of inactivity).

Thank you

```
final Handler ha = new Handler();
        ha.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {

                if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                    // set the online check
                    Boolean bolIsOnline = isNetworkAvailable();

                    if(bolIsOnline){
                        txtOnline.setText("Internet Status: Online");
                    } else{
                        txtOnline.setText("Internet Status: Offline");
                    }


                    criteria = new Criteria();
                    criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_COARSE);

                    provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
                    String strProvider = provider;

                    if(strProvider.trim().equals("gps")){
                        Log.d(TAG, "pppp: " + strProvider);
                        txtGps.setText("GPS Status: GPS enabled");
                        Toast.makeText(context, provider, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 20000, 30, locationListenerGPS);
                    } else if(strProvider.trim().equals("network")){
                        Log.d(TAG, "pppp: " + strProvider);
                        txtGps.setText("GPS Status: Network only");
                        Toast.makeText(context, provider, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 20000, 30, locationListenerGPS);
                    } else{
                        txtGps.setText("GPS Status: None");
                        Toast.makeText(context, "None", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        fusedLocationProviderClient.getLastLocation().addOnSuccessListener(actAddSighting.this, new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(Location location) {

                                final Double dblLatitude = location.getLatitude();
                                final Double dblLongitude = location.getLongitude();
                                final Double dblAltitude = location.getAltitude();

                                getInitialValues(dblLatitude, dblLongitude, dblAltitude, "Last Location");

                            }
                        });

                    }

                } else {
                    requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, MY_PERMISSION_REQUEST_FINE_LOCATION);
                    requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, MY_PERMISSION_REQUEST_COARSE_LOCATION);
                }

                ha.postDelayed(this, 20000);
            }
        }, 20000);
```

Answer (score 1):

create a global variable

```
Runnable run = new Runnable(){....}
```

use it for your Handler.in onStop(), call

```
handler.removeCallbacks(run);
```

inside your onResume(), call

```
if(run != null && handler != null){
   handler.post(run)    
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply, I've added the following in (1) Global variable declaration: `public class actAddSighting extends AppCompatActivity {

    Runnable run = new Runnable()  {
        @Override
        public void run() {}
    };
      ` and then (2) OnStop `     @Override
    public void onStop() {

        super.onStop();

        ha.removeCallbacks(run);

    }
 `  and then (3) OnResume `     @Override
    public void onResume() {

        super.onResume();

        if(run != null && ha != null){
            ha.post(run);
        }

    }  `

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure how to include code in a comment, The above changes hasn't really worked for me. Have I done something wrong?

Comment: Actually it does seem to work, but it takes a few minutes. So once I close the app I will still see the Toast message every few seconds for about 4 or 5 minutes, then it stops. I'm not sure why, but this is definitely better than what I previously had.

Comment: idk man,i just tested it before post the answer.it work and no toast till i turn the app onl.is your delay time is too small ?? i set it to 5 second and after i turn the app to background,no toast anymore

Comment: if that so,Log your time when it show the toast.you might removed your runable but not toast message.Log when it excute the Toast.show action